# typedef Using a typename

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, typedef, typename

So I had [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47227829/revisions) that I asked a question about which I realized was confusing and later edited out:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    typedef typename pair<T, T> PointType;
private:
    PointType point;
};
```

I'm not certain what the function of the `typename` in `PointType`'s definition is. It this keyword just omitted? I notice that it's frequently used in the `using` definitions to add the `*_t` extensions in type support. Perhaps that's what was intended here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary because `pair<T, T>` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), meaning that it changes depending on how `foo` was initialized.

Comment: Your'e saying it's dependent because `pair` could also be a variable template?

Comment: @StoryTeller: dependent names pre-date variable templates.  The standard committee was concerned that a classicly-designed compiler wouldn't have type information when processing `pair<T, T> PointType` and wouldn't be able to distinguish between a templated type (the correct answer) or the two statements `pair < T` and `T > PointType` (assuming `pair`, `T`, and `PointType` are all variables; don't forget about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator ).  `typename` distinguishes between those two possibilities.

Comment: @MaxLybbert - Except the example in the very page this answer links, uses a dependent name as a type, **without the typename keyword**.

Comment: In the late '90s, GCC could get the correct answer without `typename`, but then code that compiled for GCC wouldn't compile for Visual Studio.  GCC took out the extension.  Then Visual Studio added the ability to accept that kind of code.  I really don't know where things stand today.

Comment: @MaxLybbert - The very code was valid C++03. What are you talking about? It still **has** to be correct. C++11 and C++14 were backwards compatible.

Comment: I don't know why you believe the code was valid C++03 (it may have been, but I don't know your basis for the statement).  What I'm talking about is illustrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683257/why-is-typename-not-needed-here-in-visual-studio-2008-2010 (also note https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14258#c1 ).

Comment: @MaxLybbert Looks like the standard never officially requires compilers to wait till types used in a template are fully defined before implementation of a template. The only way to require that seems to be the use of `typename` as such this could be viewed as a "required `typename`" even though modern compilers all figure this out on their own.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the second type of typename use, according to cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename

Basically, you are giving a hint to the compiler: T is a template dependent type in 
`pair<T, T>`