# Why typename keyword is not needed in template dependent nested type names in VS2015?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2015, typename

I was reading about the usage of `typename` in C++ template programming (e.g. [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)). To me, it seems that when using a **dependent nested type name**, we should use `typename` for avoiding parsing ambiguity. I also checked this on Scot Meyers book [effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), item #42.

But what is strange for me is that the same example in the book, works without the `typename`. Here is the code:

```
template<class C>
void Print2nd(const C & cont)
{
   if (cont.size() >= 2)
   {
      C::const_iterator * iter1 = new C::const_iterator(cont.begin());  // why typename is NOT needed?
      C::const_iterator   iter2 = cont.begin();                         // why typename is NOT needed?
      (*iter1)++;
      iter2++;
      int value1 = **iter1;
      int value2 = *iter2;

      std::cout << "The value of 2nd with pointer is: " << value1 << std::endl;
      std::cout << "The value of 2nd without pointer is: " << value2 << std::endl;
   }
}


int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   Print2nd(vect);
   return 0;
}
```

I am using VS2015. So, the Q is that why `typename` is not needed in this context? Is there any upgrade in recent C++ compilers to avoid using `typename` in such a context? Or I am doing a mistake in the code?

**Update 1:** Thanks to @FrançoisAndrieux comment, it seems that the same thing is happening in VS2008 and VS2010, as reported in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683257/why-is-typename-not-needed-here-in-visual-studio-2008-2010).

Comment: Later compilers do warn live: https://godbolt.org/z/vw3bsQ   Have you checked the warning level?

Comment: Interestingly enough, in about two year's time, this should be well-formed.

Comment: Likely a buggy compiler - have you tested with different ones?

Comment: @TobySpeight No, I just checked with VS2015.

Comment: @Gupta That's a non-conformance issue with Visual Studio. They've had that bug for a long long time.

Comment: [SImilar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683257/why-is-typename-not-needed-here-in-visual-studio-2008-2010) but for VS2008 and VS2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) `typename` is not needed there.  In some contexts, the need for `typename` was removed, because syntactically anything there *must* be a type.

In particular:

> A qualified name that appears in type-id, where the smallest enclosing type-id is:
>
> - the type in a new expression that does not parenthesize its type;

[Quoted source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) isn't directly from the standard, but pretty reliable.

Prior to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) `typename` was needed there; it would be parsed as a value, and `new value` is not valid syntax.  In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) `typename` is *optional* in that context.

Now, [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) has no [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) features in it; what you are seeing there is MSVC's failure to properly implement [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)/[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)/[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), not a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) extension.

Comment: So it was a bug, now a feature? ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver The bug was more akin to "compiler ignores syntax errors in function that is never called, because this specific compiler does compiling at link-time".  The feature is akin to "certain things in this function are not syntax errors".  They both make certain code not break the compile, but the fact that the bug covered the feature is sort of accidental.

Answer (score 4):

`typename` **is** needed; the example program is ill-formed. If the compiler does not diagnose the issue, then it doesn't conform to the standard. A correct version is:

```
typename C::const_iterator * iter1 = new typename C::const_iterator(cont.begin());
                                      // ^^^^^^^^ this one only required until C++20
typename C::const_iterator   iter2 = cont.begin();
```

Standard quote (draft for C++17):

> [temp.res]
>
> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on atemplate-parameteris assumednot to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the keyword `typename`.

`C::const_iterator` depends on the template-parameter `C`, so it should not be assumed to be a type name unless `typename` is used. I think the statement should be interpreted as a multiplication operation, but the right hand operand is undeclared identifier and thus ill-formed.

C++20 introduces rule that allows removing the `typename` from the new-expression (latest draft):

> [temp.res]
>
> A qualified name is said to be in a type-id-only context if it appears in a type-id, **new-type-id**, or defining-type-id and the smallest enclosing type-id, new-type-id, or defining-type-id is a new-type-id, defining-type-id, trailing-return-type, default argument of a type-parameter of a template, or type-id of a static_­cast, const_­cast, reinterpret_­cast, or dynamic_­cast.

---

You might want to create a type alias for readability:

```
using const_iterator = typename C::const_iterator;
```

Or you could just use `auto`:

```
auto it = cont.begin();
```

P.S. It hardly ever makes sense to dynamically allocate an iterator.

Comment: VS is notorious for being extra permissive with omitting `typename` and `template` in these cases.

Comment: Can you provide any references to the standard for this case?

Comment: @Gupta added standard quote.

Comment: I swore I saw a change that changed the rules to permit skipping typename in some contexts.  Like base classes.  Was it just a proposal?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The base classes and member initialization list are two exception that you should NEVER use `typename` there.

Comment: But the standard states that "... unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or ...". So, if MSVC type name look-up mechanism finds the type name properly, it should not be against the standard, right?

Comment: @Gupta Except there are rules for how to do that lookup.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, mmmm ... are there such kind of rules in the standard?

Comment: @Gupta Yes, there are a lot of name lookup rules in the standard.  They are quite complex.